# Android Intent-filter problem

Tags: android, android-intent, resolution, android-contacts, intentfilter

I'm trying to write an intent-filter to select a contact from the list of contacts (for purely educational purposes... I'm learning about intents). After calling startActivity on an implicit intent, android should find my custom activity as well as the default activity as candidate Activities and let me choose which one I want to use (intent resolution).

However, with my current setup, it opens android's default contact picker without giving me the choice. Here is my intent-filter.

```
<activity android:name=".ContactPicker" android:label="PICKER" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="content" android:host="com.android.contacts" android:path="contacts" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and here is how I am calling the implicit intent on the main activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/contacts"));
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

Comment: You need to use ACTION_CHOOSER documented here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CHOOSER - sorry I don't know how to use it myself but try Googling for examples.

Comment: @MisterSquonk: That would be necessary if the user had chosen a default handler for this `Intent`. It's conceivable that the built-in contacts app is pre-determined to be the default, but I'd be surprised, as they don't do that for any other `Intents` that I've tried overriding (e.g., alternative home screens).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Any idea why filtering intents by Uri doesn't work in this case and filtering by mime type does?

Comment: @AlephNull: Content provider URIs are used to look up the MIME type. Quoting the `IntentFilter` docs, "If you specify a scheme but no type, only Intent that does not have a type (such as mailto:) will match; a content: URI will never match because they always have a MIME type that is supplied by their content provider." Usually, activities associated with a content provider filter on MIME type. Besides, in this case, you are always best served by doing what Google does. I got the above `<intent-filter>` by looking at the source code to the Contacts app.

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate your help. One last question, where can I find the source code to the contacts app?

Comment: @AlephNull: http://source.android.com -- click on the Source tab, then the Browse Source link, look for the Contacts.git repo, and click on the tree link in that row.